# Logging in Python project using structlog and it logs third party libraries which needs to be removed

Tags: python, logging, structlog

I am using structlog library to log for my Python project.
I see some third party library logs which I do not want.
How do I remove those logs?

Answer (score 2):

Logging has a number of locations where you can filter messages. Via the log level of the specific module as in `logging.getLogger(...).setLevel(...)` or via a filter attached to a logger or attached to a handler.

Comment: I am setting log level to Info for each of my module and I can change that as per module. But, then why are external libraries in site-packages are getting logged.

Comment: You need to set the log level for the external libraries so that their unwanted messages to not appear.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by adding the following in my logging setup:

```
 logging.config.dictConfig({
    'disable_existing_loggers': True, # this disables the existing loggers from logging anything.
... 
})
```